# How can I set link inside a text in Android?

Tags: java, android, hyperlink, jsoup, spannablestring

So, I am using Jsoup for web scraping. I can **scrape** the data from the web, But, the problem is I am getting the links and text separately. I want those links to set inside my texts. I am using SpannableStringBuilder so, there are a lot of links and a lot of texts. so I can't figure out how to deal with the problem as I am new to android development.

```
    private void getWebsite() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final SpannableStringBuilder 
                    builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.
                        connect("https://www.wikipedia.org/").get();
                String title = doc.title();
                Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

                builder.append(title).append("\n");

                for (Element link : links) {
                    final String url = link.attr("href");
                    builder.append("\n")
                            .append("Link: ")
                            .append(url, new URLSpan(url), 
                                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                            .append("\n")
                            .append("Text: ")
                            .append(link.text());
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                builder.append("Error : ")
                        .append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(builder.toString());
                    textView.setMovementMethod
                            (LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();}
```

I am getting output like this format.

Link : //en.wikipedia.org/

Text : English 5 678 000+ articles

Link : //ja.wikipedia.org/

Text : 日本語 1 112 000+ 記事

Link : //es.wikipedia.org/

Text : Español 1 430 000+ artículos
......
......

I want to have an output like this format,

** Texts: English 5 678 000+ articles**,
inside that line, I want to
join this link
** Link://en.wikipedia.org/**
as hyperlinked or in some way so that I can click this text and go to the webpage directly like in MS Word.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for setting text values using HTML. [Here is the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)) and Here is some sample code:

```
    String str = "Do you want to search on " + "<a href=http//www.google.com>" +
                  "Google" + "</a>" + " or " + "<a href=http//www.yahoo.com>" +
                  "Yahoo" + "</a>" + "?";

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        viewToSet.setText(Html.fromHtml(str, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        viewToSet.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
    }
```

In it, you can set values using HTML. You can also update colors, bold, italics, etc, as long as you utilize HTML properties.